# Division over different select count queries in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables and want to find the percentage of different records between them.

```
TableA(item int,value string)
TableB(item int,value string)
```

I wrote this query that works perfectly with MYSQL

```sql
SELECT 100*
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM TableA A, 
               TableB B
         WHERE A.item=B.item
               AND A.value!=B.value
       )
       /
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM TableA A
       )
 ;
```

But for a similar scenario in HIVE, this query doesn't work and fails with `NoViableAltException`
How can I do these divisions of counts in HIVE?

Comment: Issue is hive does not support noneque join ...AND A.value!=B.value

Comment: @sandeeprawat What do you mean by noneque join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values in two sub queries, and then calculate in the outer query:

```sql
select
    100 * different / total
  from
    (select
         count(*) as different
       from
         a, b
       where
         a.id = b.id and a.value <> b.value) t1,
    (select
         count(*) as total
       from
         a) t2
```

Comment: This works! Probably a better way to write queries anyway.

Comment: It should indeed work with most SQL servers - it's not limited to Hive.